# Como llenar de forma correcta un objeto usando la notación [key: type]: value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de filtrar un arreglo de objetos, el cual siempre viene con todos los campos posibles para la tabla, pero la tabla no siempre tiene dichos campos activos, debido a que los campos pueden ser activos o desactivados cuando se requieran. Asi que por ende tomo los datos de los nombres de las columnas de la tabla, como expongo debajo.

```
['referenceName', 'shipmentId', 'freightType', 
'etd', 'eta', 'notes', 'company', 'origin', 'carrier',
 'voyageNumber', 'actualDeparture']
```

Esto es uno de los objetos del arreglo

[image: json]

#### My codigo

```
console.log('elements', this.elements[0]);
    const currentsColumns = Object.keys(this.columnOptions);
    const dataTableFiltered = [];
    const elementsTable: {[key: string]: any} = {}

    this.elements.forEach((element, index: number) => {
      Object.keys(element).map((key) => {
        const elementKey = key;
        if (currentsColumns.includes(elementKey)){
          if((typeof element[key]) === 'object'){
            elementsTable['key'] = (JSON.stringify(element[elementKey]));
          }else{
            elementsTable['key'] = element[elementKey]
          }
        }
      });
    })
```

El resultado  resulta ser, una misma data repitiéndose la cantidad de objetos que traiga o tenga el arreglo en el momento, si por alguna razón, el arreglo trae 15 objetos, luego de consultar, la información que muestra es la misma, a pesar de que en consola, muestra la correcta, o al menos la que espero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se entiende a qué quieres llegar. ¿Quieres crear objetos únicamente con la estructura ['referenceName', 'shipmentId', 'freightType', 
'etd', 'eta', 'notes', 'company', 'origin', 'carrier',
 'voyageNumber', 'actualDeparture'] ?

Comment: No, la estructura debe ser dinámica, ya que la tabla se le pueden ocultar o agregar columnas acorde a lo que cada quien necesite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que si entendí bien, debería ser algo así:

```js
function Aplanar(array, cabeceras) {
    let resp = [];
    for (let i of array) {
        let obj = {};
        for (let c of cabeceras) {
            let ids = c.split(".");
            obj[c] = GetObject(i, ids);
        }
        resp.push(obj);
    }
    return resp;

}
function GetObject(objeto, id) {  
    if (id.length > 0) {
        let obj = objeto[id[0]];
        if (obj != null) {
            return GetObject(obj, id.slice(1));
        }
        return null;
    }
    return objeto;
}

//EJEMPLO 1
console.log("EJEMPLO 1 ========================");
let cabeceras = ['var1', 'var2.var3'];


let obj = [
    {
        var1: 1,
        var2: {
            var3: 3
        }
    },
    {
        var1: 1,
        var2: {
            var3: 3
        }
    },
    {
        var1: 1,
        var2: {
            var3: 3
        }

    }
];
console.log(Aplanar(obj,cabeceras));

//EJEMPLO 2
console.log("EJEMPLO 2 ========================");
let cabeceras2 = ['var1', 'var2'];

console.log(Aplanar(obj,cabeceras2));
```

Si te fijas con este código también puedes navegar entre propiedades internas. Es decir, si en la cabecera colocas

- origindDetails: Obtienes un objeto con lat,lng y countryCode
- Pero si pones: origindDetails.lat, obtienes solo el campo lat

Comment: No sé si soy yo, pero el resultado no me lo deja ver bien.

Comment: Ya pude comprender bien, excelente respuesta amigo.

Comment: Aahh que bueno. Marcala con el visto verde para que quede como correcta. Saludos

Comment: De igual forma me queda la duda, acerca de que si no conoce lo que el objeto tiene dentro, si tiene otra variable que es un objeto dentro de este, como sabría los atributos de este.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales No entendí tu duda. Yo lo que entiendo es que tienes 2 arreglos. 1) Los nombres de las variables y 2) los datos que quieres ordenar de otra manera. El algoritmo conoce lo que está adentro, porque se lo pasas con el primer arreglo.

Comment: Listo, ya entendí la cosa, bueno será de probar mañana, gracias por tu ayuda.